# Client / server communication using serialized objects

Tags: java, sockets, serialization

I try to establish a client / server connection for a mastermind game.
I though of using enumerations to represent the different pegs and made them serializable.

Then I have to implement the connection, using serversocket and getting the socket using accept and so on.
Once the connection is established, I first have to read for client objects, and it is where I am having problems...

Here is a piece of my code, which produces EOFException before I could ever do anything!
(the client data is send on user's interaction).

```
ObjectInputStream ois =
    new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
ArrayList<Peg> combination = new ArrayList<Peg>();
do
{
    combination.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        combination.add((Peg)ois.readObject());
    }
}
while (!checkCombination(combination));
ois.close();
socket.close();
```

Thank's in advance

Comment: Well given that you're only showing one-half of the code, I'm going to go ahead and blame the client.

Comment: The client does not have to give directly it's objects, as it requires user interaction. I except the socket to wait until there is something to read. Isn't it the common behavior?

Comment: the point is, it's impossible to diagnose a networking (or possibly serialization) bug without seeing the code responsible. All you're showing is some high-level interface while abstracting away the important details. You don't even show the creation of `socket`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need more details. How are you syncing up writes from the client and the reads on the server? Can you post more details?

BTW, is using raw sockets an absolute requirement? If not, try out [RMI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/index.html) which does what you want to do with much less hassle (i.e. sending across Java objects transparently and much more).

Comment: I'm knew to java so I didn't know about RMI. I'm going how does it work, thanks.

Comment: RMI put in simple terms is all about distributed objects. So for e.g. if you want to send across 4 pegs to the server for checking their validity, you can just declare a remote interface with a method `checkCombination(Quartet<Peg> pegs)`, plug in the necessary implementation at the server side and it should be done. The good thing, you no longer have to worry about marshaling/un-marshaling objects and syncing up socket communication since it's all hidden behind the RMI runtime. Not the most perfect remoting concept out there but works out pretty good for Java folks. Good luck. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting an EOFException it means the other end has closed the connection.

If you want to send a list, just send the list.  i.e.

```
// on the sender
List<Peg> list =
oos.writeObject(list);

// on the receiver
List<Peg> list = (List<Peg>) oid.readObject();
```